# Basic implementation of using microbundle not working

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, pnpm, microbundle

Please see example repo
https://github.com/inspiraller/webpack-and-microbundle

---

#### Microbundle code

**mymicrobundle/src/index.js**

```js
import React from 'react'

const MyMicroBundle = ({session}) => {
  return (
    <div>Session = {session}</div>
  )
}

export default MyMicroBundle
```

**microbundle/package.json - for output**

```json
{
 ...
  "source": "src/index.js",
  "main": "dist/index.umd.js",
  "module": "dist/index.module.js",
  "exports": "dist/index.modern.js",
  "unpkg": "dist/index.umd.js"
}
```

---

#### Importing Microbundle code

**webpack-loads-microbundle/package.json**

```json
{
"dependencies": {
    "@mymicrobundle/example": "file:../mymicrobundle",
  }
}
```

**webpack-load-microbundle/src/index.tsx**

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import MyMicroBundle from '@mymicrobundle/example'

import './index.scss'

const App = () => {
  const [session, setSession] = useState('')
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello</h1>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

Note: The microbundle package is bundled as javascript, but I'm using typescript to import it.
Though shouldn't make any difference. I'm also using pnpm instead of npm but also this should be fine as all other imports work.

Something about my path is wrong maybe.

**Error**

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@mymicrobundle/example' in 'C:\baps\react_all\webpack-and-microbundle\webpack-loads-microbundle\src'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

webpack resolves modules from its `process.cwd()/node_modules` by default.

So in your case it is looking for `@mymicrobundle/example` in `webpack-and-microbundle`(the current working directory) which is your app directory.

You need to let `webpack` know, where it needs to search in addition to your project's `node_modules`.

This can be done using the `resolve.modules` key. See docs: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvemodules

So your webpack config should have something like:

```js
 resolve: {
    modules: ['node_modules', 'path/to/@mymicrobundle/example'],
  },
```

Comment: Thanks. Your solution for me wasn't entirely complete but it steered me in the right direction. This didn't work - modules: ['node_modules', path.resolve(__dirname, '../mymicrobundle/dist')] but this did: {    alias: {
      '@mymicrobundle': path.resolve(__dirname, '../mymicrobundle/dist')
    },}

Comment: There was also another issue I realised with microbundle is that it doesn't default to bundling into an npm format - ie common js. I had to actually set the format to be --format cjs. Updating repo now to show fix.

Comment: I was wrong. I got it working with: modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, '../microbundle')],I just had to remove the dist. Now I don't need the unnecessary alias.